# local variable referenced before assignment error

Tags: python, global-variables

I'm working on a text based game in python. And I ran into a little problem. One of my class methods tells the program what to do when an enemy attacks. Here is the code

```
def attack(self, method):
    user_health_old = user_health
    self.method = method
    probs = random.randrange(1,100)
    if method == "Knife":
        while user_health > 0:
            if probs in range(1,70):
                attackWin = True
                break
            else:
                attackWin = False
                pla = player()
                pla.healthRem(7)
            if user_health < 1:
                death()
    elif method == "Hands":
        while plaHealth > 0:
            if probs in range(1,40):
                attackWin = True
                break
            else:
                attackWin = False
                pla.healthRem(7)
            if user_health < 1:
                death()
    pla = player()
    pla.attackStatus()
```

player() is the class, and this method is attack()
attackStatus() is a little after chunk that will tell the player what happened in the battle, here's the code for that

```
def attackStatus(self):
    if attackWin == True:
        print "You Win, this time"
        time.sleep(2)
    if user_health < user_health_old:
        print "But you're victory did come at a cost"
        time.sleep(2)
        print "You're new health value is: ",user_health
        time.sleep(3)
```

And a couple more lines of code, Instead of running the whole program, atm I just have it set up to run this module,

```
pla = player()
pla.attack("Knife")
```

The problem comes when I run the program. It opens the console, but immediately quits. It doesn't output any information either. I'm not quite sure what's going on, if someone could help me, I'd appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Post the full traceback.

Comment: Your variable `user_health`  is never initialized in the code you have shown us

Comment: And what is with the `break` statements that aren't in a loop?

Comment: @kindall The only `break` statements I see are within `while` loops.

Comment: Er, that was pretty dumb of me; never mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `else` block of your first function when you use `pla.healthRem(7)` you are referencing `pla` before it has been assigned a value.  From looking at the other code, it looks like you want to add `pla = player()` just above this line (or possible put `pla = player()` at the very beginning of the function).

**Edit:** After seeing your comment, this is definitely related to your use of `pla` in the function `attack()`.  If you have assignment to a name *anywhere* in a function, it is considered a local variable *everywhere* in that function.  This means that you can never access the global name `pla` if you have `pla = player()` in the function body.  You can fix this in one of the following ways:

- Take all `pla = player()` lines out of your function, this will allow any lookup of `pla` to find the global variable.
- Put `global pla` at the very top of your function, the global statement will cause every assignment to that name to modify the global version of the variable instead of creating a new local variable.
- Stop trying to use a global, when you need your player instance just use `pla = player()` inside of the function.

Comment: The weird part, is that I defined pla = player() as a global variable at the very beginning of the program. I think i defined it a couple of other times too, but it was the same value.

Comment: See my edit, you can't assign to a variable name inside of your function and still use a global variable of the same name.

Comment: thank you, I was able to fix it by just removing the global pla all together like you said.